# Postgresql date function scanning every row in every partition and is very slow performing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

**I've a big partitioned table `tbl_VehicleEntry`.
I've created a function `F_GetSysDate()` (for compatibility of my function with oracle)**

CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicleentry (

```
vehicleentry_code numeric(12,0) NOT NULL,
shift_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
shift_code numeric(1,0) NOT NULL,
booth_code numeric(2,0) NOT NULL,
.
.
N number of columns);
```

**Partitions like this...**

CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_2016 (

```
CONSTRAINT tbl_vehicleentry_2016_shift_date_check CHECK (((shift_date >= '2016-01-01'::date) AND (shift_date < '2017-01-01'::date)))
```

)
INHERITS (tbl_vehicleentry);

ALTER TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_2016 OWNER TO tms;

CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201701 (

```
CONSTRAINT tbl_vehicleentry_201701_shift_date_check CHECK (((shift_date >= '2017-01-01'::date) AND (shift_date < '2017-02-01'::date)))
```

)

INHERITS (tbl_vehicleentry);

ALTER TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201701 OWNER TO tms;

CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201702 (

```
CONSTRAINT tbl_vehicleentry_201702_shift_date_check CHECK (((shift_date >= '2017-02-01'::date) AND (shift_date < '2017-03-01'::date)))
```

)

INHERITS (tbl_vehicleentry);

ALTER TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201702 OWNER TO tms;

CREATE TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201703 (

```
CONSTRAINT tbl_vehicleentry_201703_shift_date_check CHECK (((shift_date >= '2017-03-01'::date) AND (shift_date < '2017-04-01'::date)))
```

)

INHERITS (tbl_vehicleentry);

ALTER TABLE tbl_vehicleentry_201703 OWNER TO tms;

..... And so on month wise partitions for year 2017 onward

```
-- FUNCTION: public.f_getsysdate()
-- DROP FUNCTION public.f_getsysdate();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_getsysdate(
    )
    RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    STABLE SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    V_ReturnName   VARCHAR2 ;
BEGIN  
    RETURN current_timestamp::timestamp(0);
END

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.f_getsysdate()
    OWNER TO tms;
```

**Now, when I run a query like...**

```
Explain analyze
SELECT MAX(Vehicleentry_Code) FROM tbl_VehicleEntry
WHERE Shift_Date >= f_getsysdate() - 30
```

**Or**

```
Explain analyze
SELECT MAX(Vehicleentry_Code) FROM tbl_VehicleEntry
WHERE Shift_Date >= f_getsysdate() - interval '30' day
```

I observe, it is scanning through every row of every partition of the table and making it very slow.
Below is the explanation

Aggregate  (cost=324.08..324.09 rows=1 width=32)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.68..323.88 rows=79 width=16)

```
    ->  Index Scan using isd_tbl_vehicleentry on tbl_vehicleentry  (cost=0.68..4.70 rows=1 width=8)
          Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))


    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_2015  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))


          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_2015  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_2016  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_2016  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201701  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201701  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201702  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201702  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201703  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201703  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201704  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201704  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201705  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201705  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201706  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201706  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201707  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201707  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201708  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201708  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201709  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201709  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201710  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201710  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201711  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201711  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201712  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201712  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201801  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201801  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201802  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201802  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201803  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201803  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201804  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201804  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201805  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201805  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201806  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201806  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201807  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201807  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201808  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201808  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201809  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201809  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201810  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201810  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201811  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201811  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_vehicleentry_201812  (cost=4.41..12.28 rows=3 width=16)
          Recheck Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on isd_tbl_vehicleentry_201812  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=3 width=0)
                Index Cond: (shift_date >= (f_getsysdate() - '30 days'::interval day))
```

**See it has scanned every row of every partition of my postgresql table
and making it perform very slow.
What could be wrong?

The problem is in function for sure.

Is there any alternative to make it faster?
Please help.**

Comment: If you want any response, post the `EXPLAIN` output as it is and not totally mangled.

Comment: I've already posted EXPLAIN ANALYZE output..
Please see bottom of the question

Comment: The important part in my comment is **not totally mangled**. What you posted is unreadable.

Comment: Now please check, I've edited it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the value of the function is not known at the time when the query is planned, so the optimizer doesn't know if some partitions can be excluded.

You should first query `f_getsysdate()`, then construct an SQL statement from the result and execute that. This way the limit will be a constant, and the PostgreSQL optimizer can use it.

PostgreSQL can do better if the function is `IMMUTABLE`, but based on the name I assume that that is not an option.

Comment: I did that. In my front end, I take the result of f_getsysdate() in a variable and pass it to the query and it works fine.
But the question is, the same query on oracle works blazing fast without getting its result in a variable as explained above.

How oracle handles it differently then and why postgres scanning every row of every partition.

Comment: Can't answer anything about Oracle, but unless the function is `IMMUTABLE`, PostgreSQL cannot know the result before it actually executes the function (because it might be different at execution time than at planning time). And it has to plan the query before it executes it. It might be interesting to add a feature that eliminates partitions at execution time, but nobody has written that yet.

Comment: Most important...
As you suggested to get the result of f_getsysdate() first and then pass it to the query, even if I give the date hardcoded like 

Explain analyze
SELECT MAX(Vehicleentry_Code) FROM tbl_VehicleEntry
WHERE Shift_Date >= '18-MAY-18'

it is still going in every partition and making it slow.

Oracle maintains the information about every partition and the date range in its system tables, Postgres must also be doing the same somewhere as they are working from past 40 years on this database, but I think I'm unable to figure it out.
Please let me what can be done
S

Comment: For that, you'll have to tell how the partitioned table is created, in particular the partitioning constraints.

Comment: Now Please check, I've added partition creation constraint on date range.

Comment: Sorry Laurenz, I mistakenly wrote it is going in every partition even after providing hard coded date but it is going in future partitions (since in query I've wrote >=) but it is not going backward.

But if I use function in WHERE clause, it is scanning every partition from 1st to last...
The problem is in function for sure..

Comment: So your question is answered.

Comment: The question is NOT answered yet Sir...
Why it is going in past partitions from 1st partition if I use the function f_getsysdate() or even current_timestamp::timestamp(0)
in the WHERE clause.

Please help

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. Your last two comments seems to be in contradiction: *it is going in future partitions (since in query I've wrote >=) but it is not going backward* seems to indicate that it is working as expected. Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: If I use hardcoded date, it goes in to future partitions only but if I use my function f_getsysdate() which returns current_timestamp
or 
even current_timestamp::timestamp(0) then it goes from all past partitions.

Comment: Yes, like I explained. So don't use the function.

Comment: Thanks.
Making it IMMUTABLE solved the problem but only if using..

f_getsysdate() - INTERVAL '30' DAY

and NOT in

f_getsysdate() - 30

So it is necessary that function is also immutable and I use 
- interval 'n' day
otherwise even it is slow.

Comment: Be warned that PostgreSQL may now cache the result of `f_getsysdate()` for the life time of the database session if you are using PL/pgSQL functions or prepared statements.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.
When I execute only, "SELECT F_GetSysDate" it is giving correct output every time but when I use this function in another function it is repeating its value which is causing problem.
Now what... 
I was very happy that after changing it to IMMUTABLE, my query was going only in to the partitions where it should go but now I'm facing another issue as stated above.
Please let me know if something can be done.

Comment: To reiterate - don't use a function, use a constant. It is almost never a good idea to mark a non-immutable function `IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: The problem is, my application is previously designed for Oracle and now we are migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL.
So, some of my sites are on Oracle and a few are on PostgreSQL.
Oracle handles the above issue perfectly.
If I have to give a constant value instead using the function, I will have to open the recordset and get the value of f_getsysdate() in a variable and close it and reopen it and pass the variable to the query. This is time consuming and resource consuming.
Have they handled this in Postgres 10?
Will it be helpful if I move to 10 instead of 9.6.5

Comment: If you port an application you can expect that you have to change some application code. There is no use in whining. Using a constant will work just fine in Oracle, too. Moving to PostgreSQL v10 won't make a difference.

Comment: Yes, that's true. :(
Thanks for your help. I was about to get PG10 on a machine and test the same but you saved me and I will change the code instead wasting time on that. :)

Comment: Hi Laurenz!
I came to you again with a similar query :) but this time with TO_DATE()

Though the column Shift_Date is of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE,
I need to use TO_DATE() from my front end (vb6) otherwise we get no output.
Now it Index Scan using isd_tbl_shiftassignment_2007 on tbl_shiftassignment_20** (every partition)

What to do? Will switching over to pg11 solve this problem?
I cant post the entire output of explain analyze here due to its size.

Comment: You should open a new question for that, then you can also add the execution plan and all relevant definitions.

Comment: Okay. I thought that question will be generalised and I wanted to ask to you specifically. I will write a new question. Thanks in advance.